# Переписать функцию для выдачи сдачи, используя цикл и не используя рекурсию. Я не понимаю как это сделать в цикл. Можно показать на примере

Tags: javascript, java, html

```
            function oldgetChange(num) {
                if (num >= 10) {
                    console.log(10);
                    oldgetChange(num - 10);
                } else if (num >= 5) {
                    console.log(5);
                    oldgetChange(num - 5);
                } else if (num >= 2) {
                    console.log(2);
                    oldgetChange(num - 2);
                } else if (num >= 1) {
                    console.log(1);
                    oldgetChange(num - 1);
                } else {
                    console.log("Вся сдача выдана!");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Вы, возможно, не туда попали. Здесь вы четко формулируйте проблему, показывайте ваши попытки ее решить, задаёте, собственно, вопрос.

Comment: Мне функцию надо переписать использую цикл  не использую рекурсию я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: while (num > 0) что-то делать, в зависимости от значения num

Comment: а можно на примере

Answer (score -1):

Наверное как-то так

```js
function oldgetChange(num) {
  while (num > 0) {
    if (num >= 10) {
      console.log(10);
      num -= 10;
    } else if (num >= 5) {
      console.log(5);
      num -= 5;
    } else if (num >= 2) {
      console.log(2);
      num -= 2;
    } else if (num >= 1) {
      console.log(1);
      num -= 1;
    }
  }
  console.log("Вся сдача выдана!");
}

oldgetChange(44);
```

Comment: И кто против такого решения? Прошу высказаться

Comment: Вы ответили на плохо сформулированный вопрос низкого качества. Отвечая на подобные вопросы, вы тем самым показываете, что задавать такие вопросы нормально и что они будут находить ответы. Я не считаю, что это хороший подход.

Comment: @GreatTech и при чём тут ответ если вам не нравиться вопрос, нажмите на тревогу внизу вопроса и не понижаете репутацию тем кто хотят помочь

Comment: Я же написал: «Отвечая на подобные вопросы, вы тем самым показываете, что задавать такие вопросы нормально и что они будут находить ответы»

Comment: @GreatTech тогда давай всем подряд портить репутацию из-за того что вы считаете это вопрос "тупым". Насколько я понимаю тут надо помогать новичкам или тем кто столкнулся с проблемами. А вы сравниваете всех с собой, типа "Чё за изичный вопрос давайка я ему минус поставлю и тем кто хочет ему помочь"

Comment: @GreatTech если вы начнёте изучать какой-то новый язык и столкнётесь с сложностьями и спросите кого-то кто знает и он вам такой "Какой ты неумный, да это за пять секунд решается а ты не знаешь, лучше брось учить". Это не нормально

Comment: Вы перепутали простой вопрос и некачественный вопрос. Некачественный вопрос задается человеком, который не заботится о том, насколько удобно его читать и насколько понятна его проблема. Простой вопрос - это неплохо. Плохо, это когда ты задаёшь вопрос и тебе нет дела до того, насколько хорошо ты его составил. Я считаю, что не стоит позволять таким вопросам-сорнякам плодиться, удобряя их ответами.

Comment: @ПростаMiha  просто забей на него. Ты тут ради репутации или все таки "тут надо помогать новичкам или тем кто столкнулся с проблемами" ? =)

Comment: @alezhu для всего :P

Answer (score -2):

```
  function getCoffee(price, name) {
    let money = $('#money');
    let value = +money.val();
    let display = $('#display');
    if (value >= price) {
      value -= price; //money.value - price;
      money.val(value);
      const result =
        'Ваш ' + name + ' готов! <br> Сдача: ' + getChange(value);
      display.html(result);
    } else {
      display.html('У Вас не хватает денег для покупки ' + name);
    }
  }

  function getChange(num) {
    let coins_set = [];
    for (const coin of [10, 5, 2, 1]) {
      if (num == 0) break;
      const count = parseInt(num / coin);
      num = num % coin;
      if (count > 0) {
        coins_set.push(coin + 'x' + count);
      }
    }
    const result = '[' + coins_set.join(',') + ']';
    return result;
  }
```